# Count total rows with same value, and echo the value of the row value

Tags: php, html

I am working on something for my place of employment, and I want to be able to show the employee the "most favorite color" ..

When an employee uploads using the PHP CRUD I am developing, they can enter

`White, Yellow, Black, Green, Red, Orange, Brown, Purple, Pink, Grey, Blue` as part of the "batch control" system.

What I am wanting to do, is count the total rows containing whatever color it is, and echo out the "most used color"

My table:

```
<tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>TOS</th>
                                    <th>Tag Batch #1</th>
                                    <th>Tag Batch #2</th>
                                    <th>Colour</th>
                                    <th>User</th>
                                    <th>Wastage</th>
                                    <th>Reason</th>
                                    <th>Laser</th>
                                    <th>Options</th>
                                </tr>
```

Above all of that on my index page is a

```
<div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="md-title nomargin">Most Favorite Colour</h5>
                                        <h1 class="mt5">###</h1>
                                    </div><!-- media-body -->
```

How would I go about showing the user what the most uploaded color is?

My database table is like the following;

`ID | Date | TOS | tags1 | tags2 | colour | user | wastage | reason | comments`

An example output would be

````
2021-06-02
500110
169700
Pink
My_Name
4
2021-06-30 18:39:2```
````

Comment: What is your current PHP code? you can easily get the most selected colour via sql

Comment: This is not how it works, you write code and if needed we help you, we dont write your code.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(ColorID), ColorName
FROM Colors
GROUP BY ColorName;

Comment: Apologies for lack of information.

I have tried things like ```<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name"; if ($result=mysqli_query($db,$sql)) { $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result); echo $rowcount; } ?>```

Which is what I am using for another part of the index page, but I haven't saved anything in terms of what I've previously used.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(ID) as totalcount, 
           colour
    FROM Colors
    GROUP BY colour) t 
ORDER BY totalcount DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This query will fetch most inserted color in table with count, so you can use it.Use your table fields and table name proper in above query.

Comment: I appreciate you helping me out. Since I am still learning as I go, how do I use the query then echo the result? Would the result be a number or would it show the most used color name?

Comment: Thanks! you can run query in MySQL administration tools like phpmyadmin etc. ,Above query output will be two fields one is totalcount and other is name of color.If you want only name of most used colour then you can use
SELECT t.colour FROM (SELECT COUNT(ID) as totalcount,colour FROM Colors GROUP BY colour) t order by totalcount desc limit 1;

Comment: Thank you, it does work exactly how I wanted. I am now using the same query for "User with most uploads" -- Appreciate the help. This is how I am echoing it

```<?php $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT COUNT(ID) as totalcount, col FROM table_name GROUP BY col) t order by totalcount desc limit 1;"); while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ echo $result['col']; } ?>```

Where `col` is the colour name in the database.